# Is it possible to create network shares with multiple DHCP servers running on the same network?

Tags: network-shares, dhcp-server

I am planning on installing Fedora and using [Amahi](https://www.amahi.org/) as a Media Server/NAS in my house.

I currently have a network with 2 wireless routers, one acts as the DHCP server and the other is just an AP. The one that is a DHCP server is directly connected to a modem. I will be installing Amahi on a machined connected to the AP. I read that Amahi prefers to be the DHCP server for the network. Now I do not want to change the existing DHCP server but I am plan to give each DHCP server a different range of addresses to serve.

1. **I would like to access my shares on Amahi from the devices who were assigned their IP from the second DHCP server. Will this be
   possible?**
2. **Also does it matter if the Amahi DHCP server is not directly connected to the modem (modem -> router -> AP -> Amahi)? Will I have
   problems with QOS?**

Comment: The use of two DHP servers you are doing is purely casual: each device will be served by the fastest DHCP server. Is this how you want to divide your machines? In a casual way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**
Two DHCP in the same physical network can't be used to serve IP addresses for different ranges.

Why?
A network card, configured to lease addresses from a DHCP, sends a packet (DHCP broadcast) to all computers. The computer running a DHCP server will answer with the next free IP address (and other settings configured for the client). When there are multiple DHCP servers, all will answer and send the IP informations. But the client will accept only the first he gets.

On the most DHCP servers it is possible to configure serveral ranges.

It may be wanted that serveral ranges serve different setting (like a different gateway). This must be configured on one DHCP in the respective range configuration.

If one client (precisely its network card) must only get the IP adrress from one range, this can be solved using reservations for the client. This connects the mac address of the network card with a static setting at the DHCP (including a quasi static IP for the client).

(DHCPs may be configured for failover purposes. Then there are more DHCPs, but this is a very special configuration and the client will get the same informations regardless to the DHCP which answers).

**Post before edit, suggsting the use of the Amahi DHCP**
Don't run multiple DHCP servers in one network. It will cause trouble. (Look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/809589/running-two-dhcp-servers-in-the-same-network))

Servers an routers should always have a static IP. (e.q. 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.2). This IPs have to be excluded from the IP range the DHCP is using.

I guess that Amahi is sharing more informations through DHCP to the clients than a normal router does. So it makes sense to use Amahi's DHCP.

Probably it will be sufficient to do that:

- disable DHCP on the router
- make sure that the static IPs (of router(s) and Amahi itself) are excluded on the dhcp range of Amahi
- add the address of the router to the dhcp settings of Amahi

Comment: I already know why running two DHCP servers on one network might be a hassle but I will be dealing with that by giving each DHCP server a different range to serve. I want to know if the shares will be accessible and if I will have problems with QoS because of my setup.

Comment: When the clients are on the same (physical) network - how do they tell the DHCPs what range they belong to?

Comment: In my router setting I can tell the server to assign from only a range of "192.168.1.xxx - 192.168.1.yyy" where xxx - yyy can be from 1-255. This way each server will only assign a unique ip to each client from the given range. All I have to do is tell each DHCP to serve different ranges. And the problem of who assigns the client an IP is whichever server responds to the "Discover" first.

Comment: Now for the devices that I will always need on the network, I can assign them static IPs.

Comment: Selecting ranges is important when you have clients with static IPs. 192.168.1.1 - .100 are my static IPs and .101 - 254 should be used for dynamic IPs. So will define the range .101 - 254 on your DHCP to avoid conflicts with the static IPs. A network card (configured for DHCP) is stupid. It sends a network packed to all clients and asks for an IP address. The fastest DHCP will give it the next free address. Maybe I'm wrong, but I dont' know a way how to tell a DHCP that it musn't answer at specific network cards.

Comment: You are not wrong @boboes, this is a race condition and the fastest DHCP server will offer a lease to the client asking for one. The issue here might be that one will be full while the other is empty. This situation could also lead to two machines being unable to communicate with one another because of different DHCP options between the 2 DHCP server. A rule of thumb: never have a "rogue" DHCP server on a network.

Answer (score 1):

1) As far as multiple DHCP servers sure....

You mention the DHCP server is directly connected to the Modem....would it be too hard for you in your case to allow Static IP to the AP, which would give its own DHCP entries?

Comment: So you are saying that I give my AP/Router a static IP, which then runs its own DHCP? Why would I do that, is there any advantage over what I currently have?

Comment: harrymc  pretty much summed it up best

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely possible to have multiple DHCP servers running on the same network segment,
if the limitations of this architecture are understood and planned-for.

The Microsoft TechNet article [DHCP Best Practices](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780311%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) says :

> When started, each DHCP client broadcasts a DHCP discover message
>   (DHCPDISCOVER) to its local subnet to attempt to find a DHCP server.
>   Because DHCP clients use broadcasts during their initial startup, you
>   cannot predict which server will respond to the DHCP discover request
>   of a client if more than one DHCP server is active on the same subnet.
>
> For example, if two DHCP servers service the same subnet and its
>   clients, clients can be leased at either server. Actual leases
>   distributed to clients can depend on which server responds first to
>   any given client. **Later, the server first selected by the client to
>   obtain its lease might be unavailable when the client attempts to
>   renew**.
>
> If renewal fails, the client then delays trying to renew its lease
>   until it enters the rebinding state. In this state, the client
>   broadcasts to the subnet to locate a valid IP configuration and
>   continue without interruption on the network. At this point, a
>   different DHCP server might respond to the client request. If this
>   occurs, the responding server might send a DHCP negative
>   acknowledgement message (DHCPNAK) in reply. This can occur even if the
>   original server that first leased the client is available on the
>   network.

Therefore the problems in such an architecture that I can see and their solutions :

1. **Conflicts between IP addresses**
   These can simply be solved by splitting the allocation ranges between the two DHCP servers.
   Further fail-safe measure can be the permanent binding of MAC addresses to IP addresses in the
   DHCP server (if it has this option).
2. **Renewal of DHCP leases might be very slow**
   This will happen if the renewing client always happens upon the wrong DHCP server,
   until the client gives up and requests a new lease.
   But this is not a problem if the leases have a sufficient period of validity.
   For example, 24 hours is more than enough if all the computers are turned off at night.
   24 hours is the default used by most DHCP servers, but is also normally a configuration
   option in these servers.
   Computers in such a network should not be set to hibernate,
   because when waking up the DHCP lease might need renewal.